# Cant access Axio's promise status

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I am using axios and i made a wrapper for it.One of the method looks like this:

```
this.post = function(){

 var request = axios{

  method:'post',
  url:'someurl.com',

 }.then(()=>console.log('success'))
  .catch(()=>console.log('fail'));

return request

}
```

This is a request object when i log it to the console:

    `Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}`

I cant get  `[[PromiseStatus]]` property.

`request['[[PromiseStatus]]'] // => return undefined`
`request['PromiseStatus'] // => return undefined`

I was looking quite alot before posting here.Anyone want to help?Cheers!

Comment: why do you need to access this - note: these are internal properties useful (maybe) for debugging,

Comment: I have different requests and im checking if each one of them is resolved.I know that you can make [concurrent requests](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#concurrency) but my attempt seemed to me a bit easier.My way is somewhat wrong?

Comment: Thanks @Jaromanda i didnt know that there is something like internal properties.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is an inspection of the Promise object and not the properties.
To get the actual promise status you can try [promise-status-async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-status-async)